# Java regular expression to extract parts of a string

Tags: java, regex, match

Consider a long string with the following format (the parentheses are not part of the actual text, just added here to show the group limits):

```
(text, excluding the '=' character)(space)(ab = c d)(space)(e = f)(space)(g = h i):(space)(other text)
```

How can the above be broken into the following 3 groups with a single Java regex?

```
text, excluding the equals character
ab = c d e = f g = h i
 other text
```

The first group is random text (without any '=' character), the second is a (potentially long) series of key-value pairs, where there is no ':' character and at least the values can have spaces in between, and the 3rd group is another part of random text. The second group is separated from the 3rd group by the ':' character.

The following regex would "almost" work:

```
([^=]+)([^:]+):(.*)
```

but the groups it produces, are:

```
text, excluding the equals character ab
= c d e = f g = h i
other text
```

Is there any way to "back-reference" the last part of the first group (i.e., the "ab" string) so that it is included in the second group instead of the first group?

Comment: Show actual string example and your expected output.

Comment: The example in the question is very close to the actual string.

Comment: How would one know there `"text, excluding the '=' character"` ends and where `"a b"` starts?

Comment: That's the problem - you don't. The second group is all the key-value pairs, starting with "ab", but that is not a previously known "word", either.

Comment: But then the problem is ambiguous. If you can't explain how you reached `a b = c d e = f g = h i` as middle part, how can we help you write a regexp for it?!

Comment: Ok, so the middle part is at least `"one_word = some value another_word = some other value"`?

Comment: Yes, the second group is all the key-value pairs. Let's make the assumption that the first key does not have a space, i.e. it is "ab" and not "a b". It may actually have a space, but let's simplify the problem like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should break up the string using a regular expression:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegexMatching {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^=]+) ([^=]+ = [^:]+): (.+)");
         Matcher m = p.matcher("text, excluding the equals character ab = c d e = f g = h i: other text");

         if (m.find()) {
             //System.out.println(m.group(0));
             System.out.println(m.group(1));
             System.out.println(m.group(2));
             System.out.println(m.group(3));
         }
    }

}
```

Note that the group with index 0 (commented out), will return the whole string.

About:

> Is there any way to "back-reference" the last part of the first group
>   (i.e., the "ab" string) so that it is included in the second group
>   instead of the first group?

With the above regexp, we force the first word of the key-value pairs to be in the second capturing group. (This is not a "back-reference in the context of regexp terminology, because that usually means referring back to one of the capturing groups.)

EDIT: Updated the regexp, according to the edit in the question.
EDIT2: Answered back-reference question.

Comment: Thanks, but it will not work. You are assuming that the key-value pairs are "ab = "... etc. That is not the case. The key-value pairs can be any words combinations, separated by space and '='. You may wan tot consider removing your answer, because apparently there are people who prefer to spend their energy in downvoting, instead of helping to solve the problem. I gave you +1 to balance off a negative vote that you got. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated the regexp according to your edit in the question. The new version gives me the output you need.